# Python 3 program about finding the average of integers in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
list1 = []

while True:
    num=input("enter a number or input q to quit or input a for the average\n")
    if isinstance(num, int):
        list1.append(num)
    elif isinstance(num, str):
        if num == "q":
            exit()
        elif num == "a":
            print(list1)
        else:
            print("stop")
```

I'm a python beginner, and I've made this program to find the average of integers in a list, but for some reason it does not add any integers to the list. I don't know why it doesn't work

Comment: What does the `input` function return in Python 3.x?

Comment: you're just appending numbers in list and print list while user press 'a'.

Comment: `num` is a string, not an integer. Because `isinstance` is returning false, nothing is being added.

Comment: Debuggers like [PythonTutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) can help you find the reason for seemingly strange script behavior. ForceBru and Rohan have already explained, why your list does not contain anything.